# Changing the anchor point for a View when placing using .position()

Tags: swiftui

In the following example, a view is placed relative to an Image, in this case in the bottom-right corner:

```swift
struct RelativePositionExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("cookies")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("Hello")
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .position(x: geometry.size.width * 1.0, y: geometry.size.height * 1.0)
                }
            )
    }
}
```

The "anchor point" for .position is the center of the Text view:

[image]

I tried using an alignment guide like described in [Change Button Anchor Point SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58617739/128083), this didn't do the trick.

Is there a way to express "place based on the top/left or bottom/right corner" in such a case? (not based on Spacer - the position doesn't need to be necessarily in the corner, it could be 30% of the width f.e., 30% referring to the left edge of the positioned view).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just place text into image corner then there is simpler solution.

```
var body: some View {
    Image("cookies")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .overlay(
            ZStack {
                Text("Hello")
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        )
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in the last sentence of my question, the position doesn't need to be necessarily in the corner, I am looking for a general solution that would work also for something like 70% of the width but based on to the left or right edge of the positioned view. I only choose 100% in the example to clearly demonstrate the center-anchor-point behaviour in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very general way to relatively position overlay views anyway you like. Try it in Playground.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

extension View {
    func overlay<V: View>(alignment: Alignment, relativePos: UnitPoint = .center, _ other: V) -> some View {
        self
            .alignmentGuide(alignment.horizontal, computeValue: { $0.width * relativePos.x })
            .alignmentGuide(alignment.vertical, computeValue: { $0.height * relativePos.y })
            .overlay(other, alignment: alignment)
    }
}
    

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .overlay(alignment: .center, relativePos: UnitPoint(x: 0.3, y: 0.3), Capsule().fill(Color.green).frame(width: 40, height: 20))
            .overlay(alignment: .center, relativePos: UnitPoint(x: 0.7, y: 0.3), Capsule().fill(Color.green).frame(width: 40, height: 20))
            .overlay(alignment: .center, relativePos: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.75), Text("Hello"))
            .overlay(alignment: .center, relativePos: .bottom, Divider())
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```